# How to create a dashboard from rest service inside pentaho?

Tags: json, rest, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am creating Pentaho dashboard, currently it has 3 ways to feed data. I need to provide the data to the dasbhboard through a rest service. Is it possible? If possible how can i make it?Please provide some samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDA, the data access plugin is itself a REST service. And it accepts as a datasource a PDI transformation which can in turn connect to other RESTful services to get data out and process it.

Comment: can you tell me the steps to do that?, i just want to pass the service and get the data

Comment: You will have to read the documentation of the plugins I mentioned. It's not as easy as filling in the blanks and say "point to this service". You will need to work around the data structure and process it as you need.

Comment: CDA _is_ a REST service; it allows you to connect to a PDI transformation which allows you to connect to other REST services. If I understood your question correctly, you don't need to change any source code.

Comment: i know it can be done through data transformation, is there a way we can access the service from pentaho user console dashboard!

Comment: Install CDA. Create a CDA file. Run a query. Open a browser debugger, look into the network tab. The queries will be shown there, together with its parameters. GHave you read CDA's documentation?